# Binomial Distribution where n = X?

Tags: statistics, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

I am looking at a sample of tests which test whether or not a program runs to completion or fails.

> In the first run of tests (around $1000$), we saw a failure rate of around $0.13$. There was then a fix applied to the program, and I'm trying to figure out how many tests would have to be run to have $95\%$ confidence that the program would not fail again, and therefore that the fix has succeeded.

My initial thoughts were to modify the binomial distribution, setting the number of trials equal to the number of successes. This just leaves you with $p^x = P(X)$. I wasn't sure if this would be an accurate test for the data that I wanted to run though, because I wasn't sure if the binomial distribution can work correctly if you are assuming there are $0$ failures while also assuming the success rate is less than $1$. If you have any suggestions for other tests I could look at that might work, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

No amount of testing will guarantee the program will never fail, but you can test enough to verify that it is unlikely that the failure rate is $0.13$ or more.

If we assume (the null hypothesis) that the failure rate is $p=0.13$ and that the tests are independent, then the number of failures in $n$ trials follow a Binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, so the probability of zero failures in $n$ trials is $(1-p)^n$.  If we would like that probability to be less than $0.01$, say, then we want to choose $n$ so that 
$$(1-p)^n < 0.01$$ or equivalently,
$$ n > \frac{\log(0.01)}{\log(1-p)}$$
For $p = 0.13$, $n \ge 34$ will work, so if you observe zero failures in $34$ tests, it is unlikely that the failure rate is still $0.13$.

Comment: How would I logically explain why a higher failure rate leads to a lower number of trials, in this instance?

Comment: The more roaches there are in your house, the easier it is to detect that you have roaches.. ;-)

Comment: Why would we want the probability of zero failures in n trials to be low, rather than high?

Comment: We _assume_, for the sake of argument, a null hypothesis.  We then compute how the probability of our observations, given that assumption.  If the probability is low, that casts doubt on our assumption, i.e. the assumption is likely false.  For example, suppose we have a coin we suspect may not be fair, and we toss the coin 20 times and it comes up heads every time.  Under the assumption of a fair coin, that's very unlikely; the probability is 2^-20; so our assumption that the coin is fair is doubtful.